# How to extract multiple *.tgz files to multiple directories using PERL?

Tags: linux, perl, tar

I am learning PERL lang. 
I have forced (and little confused) the issue with extracting *.tgz files.
My point which I want to achieve is to extract multiple *.tgz files to multiple folders.

So the structure comes:

```
first.tgz
sec.tgz
third.tgz
...
n.tgz
```

I want to extract these files to directories:

```
first (extracted first.tgz)
sec (extracted sec.tgz)
thidrd (extracted third.tgz)
etc.
```

Can someone help me with this, or give some hints how to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [atool](http://www.nongnu.org/atool/):

```
use autodie qw(:all);
use Path::Tiny qw(path);
for my $archive (qw(first.tgz sec.tgz third.tgz n.tgz)) {
    my $basename = path($archive)->basename('.tgz');
    path($basename)->mkpath;
    system qw(aunpack -X), $basename, $archive;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @daxim, but the question is - what if these *.tgz files are milion? Idea is how to iterate them without knowing their names.

Comment: Path::Tiny has an `iterator` method.

Comment: Also `children` for the contents of a directory non-recursively.